# Captcha for Joomla 1.5 and VirtueMart 1

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, captcha, virtuemart

I have a website running on Joomla 1.5 with the old Virtuemart installed. Is there a captcha extension which can be used for VirtueMart product enquiry form. I have tried and looked all over the web and Joomla extensions and could not find one that works with both Joomla and Virtuemart old versions.

I unfortunately cannot upgrade VM or Joomla to the new packages on the website.

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great tutorial, if you encounter problems, don't mind to ask :)

http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=66513.0

Comment: @BRad Try the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20140722224213/http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=66513.0